# Spring DI - Autowired property is null in a REST service

Tags: spring, dependency-injection, nullpointerexception, jersey, autowired

I'm getting started with Spring DI, but I'm struggling with dependency injection and the worse part is that I'm not even sure why as it seems ok to me. Hopefully you guys can help me out!

**The problem is that a property annotated as *@Autowired* is always *null***

I've got a few projects with Maven structure:

- com.diegotutor.lessondeliver
- com.diegotutor.utility

I'm running the examples over Tomcat 7

I'm using the following dependencies in my `pom.xml`:

- spring-context 3.2.4
- spring-web 3.2.4
- jersey-server 1.17.1
- jersey-core 1.17.1
- jersey-servlet 1.17.1

The simple idea is to have a RESTful service that through Dependency Injection is able to print out the value of a property located in a config file located at: `D:\configuracion.conf.`

At **com.diegotutor.utility** I have the following interface:

```
package com.diegotutor.utility;

public interface ConfigService {

    public String getProperty(final String propertyName);
}
```

Implemented by:

```
package com.diegotutor.utility.impl;

import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.Reader;
import java.util.Properties;

import com.diegotutor.utility.ConfigService;

public class PropertyFileConfigService implements ConfigService{

Properties prop;

public PropertyFileConfigService (final InputStream input) throws IOException {
    if(input == null) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Input stream can't be null");
    }
    prop = new Properties();
    prop.load(input);
}

public PropertyFileConfigService (final String fileName) throws IOException {
    final FileInputStream input = new FileInputStream(fileName);
    prop = new Properties();
    prop.load(input);
}

public PropertyFileConfigService(final Reader input) throws IOException {
    prop = new Properties();
    prop.load(input);
}

public String getProperty(final String propertyName) {
    return prop.getProperty(propertyName);
}

}
```

And at **com.diegotutor.lessondeliver** I have the RESTful service where I would like to use an injected instance of the ConfigService:

```
package com.diegotutor.lessondeliver;

import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;

import org.apache.commons.logging.Log;
import org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import com.diegotutor.utility.ConfigService;

@Path("/")
@Component
public class HelloWorld {

private static final Log log = LogFactory.getLog(HelloWorld.class);

@Autowired
private ConfigService configService;

@Path("/helloworld")
@GET
@Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
public String getHello() {
    String host = configService.getProperty("host");
    return "Hello World! HOST" + host;
            // configService IS NULL!! 
            //SO IT THROWS A NULLPOINTER EXCEPTION WHEN INVOKING getProperty ON IT
}
}
```

Finally at `/com.diegotutor.lessondeliver/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/service-beans.xml` I have the following XML application context file, where I use the implementation of `ConfigService (PropertyFileConfigService)` injecting on it the path for the configuration file to read:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

<bean id="configService" class="com.diegotutor.utility.impl.PropertyFileConfigService">
    <constructor-arg type="java.lang.String"
        value="D:\configuracion.conf" />
</bean>

<context:component-scan base-package="com.diegotutor" />

</beans>
```

*Obviously I have specified in the `web.xml` of this `com.diegotutor.lessondeliver` web app that I want `service-beans.xml` as ConfigLocation and a listener `ContextLoaderListener`, and the RESTful service relies on ServletContainer*

If I'm specifying context:component-scan to look for Components in `com.diegotutor` as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17589757/problems-with-autowire-annotation-null) and I'm forcing object creation through Spring by not using any new Statement as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18091939/autowired-field-get-null), **Why am I getting the annotated configService as null? Why Spring is unable to inject an instance of `com.diegotutor.utility.impl.PropertyFileConfigService`?**

Any help will be much appreciated!

Thank you

EDITED:

As requested, my web.xml is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" 
xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" 
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee     http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" 
id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">

 <display-name>com.diegotutor.lessondeliver</display-name>

 <context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/service-beans.xml</param-value>
 </context-param>

 <listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
 </listener>

 <servlet>
  <servlet-name>jersey-servlet</servlet-name>
  <servlet-class>
         com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer
  </servlet-class>
  <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
 </servlet>

 <servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>jersey-servlet</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
 </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

Comment: Please post your web.xml.

Comment: Sotirios, thanks for your quick reply. I have now added the web.xml

Comment: I am missing jersey-spring integration - http://www.mkyong.com/webservices/jax-rs/jersey-spring-integration-example/

Comment: I don't believe the `HelloWorld` object you see is the one generated by Spring and therefore the field isn't injected. You might want to look at [this](http://www.mkyong.com/webservices/jax-rs/jersey-spring-integration-example/) for some Spring-Jersey integration.

Comment: Excellent, I did not know Jersey and Spring might have conflicts working together needing integration, but that really could explain the issue if Jersey is instantiating another HelloWorld totally unaware of the Spring @Component. I'll try what you said. Thank you very much!

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis does this work with jersey 2.8 too?

Comment: @eskalera Sorry, but I don't know jersey well enough to help. If it is a newer version i would guess that it should work.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You were right!
It seems that the problem is that Jersey is totally unaware of Spring and instantiates its own object. In order to make Jersey aware of Spring object creations (through dependency injection) I had to integrate Spring + Jersey.

To integrate:

1. Add maven dependencies

   ```
   <dependency>
       <groupId>com.sun.jersey.contribs</groupId>
       <artifactId>jersey-spring</artifactId>
       <version>1.17.1</version>
       <exclusions>
           <exclusion>
               <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
               <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
           </exclusion>
           <exclusion>
               <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
               <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
           </exclusion>
           <exclusion>
               <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
               <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
           </exclusion>
           <exclusion>
               <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
               <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
           </exclusion>
       </exclusions>
   </dependency>
   ```
2. Use SpringServlet for jersey-servlet in `web.xml`

   ```
   <servlet>
       <servlet-name>jersey-servlet</servlet-name>
       <servlet-class>
           com.sun.jersey.spi.spring.container.servlet.SpringServlet
       </servlet-class>
       <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
   </servlet>
   ```

Now the @Autowired works properly and the object is not null anymore.

I'm a little bit confused about the exclusions I have to use in maven when using jersey-spring dependency, but that's another issue :)

Thank you!

Comment: the answer is regarding jersey 1.x

Answer (score 5):

Integration Spring with **Jersey 2** (`org.glassfish.*`):

### Maven

Some dependencies may be unnecessary, please check & clear it after things got working.

```
    <properties>
        <jersey.version>2.5</jersey.version>
    </properties>

    <!-- Jersey -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
        <version>${jersey.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
        <!-- if your container implements Servlet API older than 3.0, use "jersey-container-servlet-core" -->
        <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet</artifactId>
        <version>${jersey.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-client</artifactId>
        <version>${jersey.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.test-framework.providers</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-test-framework-provider-inmemory</artifactId>
        <version>${jersey.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Jersey + Spring -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.ext</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-spring3</artifactId>
        <version>${jersey.version}</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
```

### web.xml

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>my-rest-service</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
        <param-value>my.package.with.rest.services</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>my-rest-service</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/api/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

### applicationContext.xml

During the Spring upgrading I had to move it from `/main/webapp/WEB-INF/` to `/main/resources/` ([details](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12574877/1192987)).

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-2.5.xsd">

    <context:annotation-config />
    <context:component-scan base-package="my.package.with.rest.services" />
</beans>
```

### Example REST service

```
public interface MyService
{
    String work(String s);
}

...

@Service
public class MyServiceImpl implements MyService
{
    @Override
    public String work(String s)
    {
        return "Hello, " + s;
    }
}

...

@Path("demo/")
@Component
public class DemoRestService
{
    @Autowired
    private MyService service;

    @GET
    @Path("test")
    public Response test(@FormParam("param") String par)
    {
        try
        {
            String entity = service.work(par);
            return Response.ok(entity).build();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return Response.status(Status.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR).entity("Epic REST Failure").build();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: can you please paste all code, because i have spent alot of time for this task, - no good luck.

Comment: I've added the example. Maybe you should verify all annotations first. Let me know if it helped.

Answer (score 5):

or you can simply extend SpringBeanAutoWiringSupport class. Like this: `public class DemoRestService extends SpringBeanAutoWiringSupport`. By extending this support class, properties of your service class can be auto-wired.

Comment: Perfect! I'm using annotations only and I want none of the xml or maven dependency clutter.

Answer (score 2):

Another possible option is to manually invoke autowiring in your jersey resource:

```
@Context
private ServletContext servletContext;

@PostConstruct
public void init() {
    SpringBeanAutowiringSupport.processInjectionBasedOnServletContext(this, servletContext);
}
```

Hmm, you get a "manual autowiring"...