# spring autowire is not working returning null

Tags: java, spring, autowired

i'm learning spring now. here's my sample code. i'm using jersey, spring, hibernate, and mysql for my REST service.

`CustomerServiceImpl.java` which is REST endpoint (partial code)

```
package com.samples.service.impl;

@Path("customers")
public class CustomerServiceImpl implements CustomerService {

    private static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(CustomerServiceImpl.class);

    @Autowired
    CustomerBO customerBO;
```

here is `CustomerBOImpl.java` (partial code)

```
package com.samples.BO.impl;

@Component
public class CustomerBOImpl implements CustomerBO {

    @Autowired
    CustomerDAO customerDAO;

    @Autowired
    CustomerAdapter customerAdapter;
```

CustomerDAOImpl.class
    package com.samples.DAO.impl;

```
@Repository
public class CustomerDAOImpl implements CustomerDAO {
```

this is `applicationContext.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
              http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
              http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
              http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
              http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx 
              http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.1.xsd">

<context:property-placeholder location="classpath*:database.properties"/>
<context:component-scan base-package="com.samples"/>
<context:annotation-config />

</beans>
```

this is first few lines of exception i'm getting.

```
http-bio-8090-exec-1] [class: CustomerServiceImpl] INFO  - list all customers
[http-bio-8090-exec-1] [class: CustomerServiceImpl] INFO  - customerBO is null
May 08, 2014 10:55:29 AM com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerResponse mapMappableContainerException
SEVERE: The RuntimeException could not be mapped to a response, re-throwing to the HTTP container
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.samples.service.impl.CustomerServiceImpl.getAllCustomers(CustomerServiceImpl.java:40)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.JavaMethodInvokerFactory$1.invoke(JavaMethodInvokerFactory.java:60)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider$TypeOutInvo
```

this is web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee
http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
version="2.5">
    <display-name>Employee Service</display-name>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>

        classpath*:applicationContext.xml
        </param-value>
    </context-param>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>initializeContextOnStartup</param-name> 
        <param-value>true</param-value> 
    </context-param>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class> 
    </listener>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>jersey-serlvet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
            <init-param>
            <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages</param-name>
            <param-value>com.samples.service</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>com.sun.jersey.api.json.POJOMappingFeature</param-name>
            <param-value>true</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>jersey-serlvet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>


</web-app>
```

so if i'm understanding how this works correctly, i'm `configuring xml` to have my components autoscanned by providing the package under which i want to run autoscan. and for objects that i want to autowire. in `CustomerServiceImpl` class, i use @autowired for `customerBO` object which should have been scanned by @Component annotation on CustomerBOImpl.class definition. can you please help why my auto-scan is not picking up autowired customerBO object?
thanks.

Comment: i'm using spring and jersey. so i believe jersey should look for @Path to find resources?

Comment: yes i am. full implementation uses maven, spring, jersey, hibernate, c3p0, mysql. but it is still lite weight exercise for me. this is simple REST service.

Comment: Remember having to do this - see this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19745187/spring-di-autowired-property-is-null-in-a-rest-service#19751981)

Comment: How are you instantiating the `CustomerServiceImpl`?  Spring should throw an exception if it fails to autowire a dependency...

Comment: chris, i'm using jersey so i'm using @Path annotation for jersey to pick up the resource. i don't see any autowire dependency errors in the log. it's just that autowired bean is actually null which is my problem.

Comment: reimeus, thanks for the link. i did try using spring servlet in my web.xml but i'm still getting the same error. i added my web.xml to my original posting

Comment: Provide the code where you call this `CustomerServiceImpl#getAllCustomers` method. Otherwise, there could be several reasons for your code to throw NPE.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19896870/why-is-my-spring-autowired-field-null

Answer (score 4):

I suspect the problem is your `CustomerServiceImpl` class is being instantiated outside of Spring, either by the servlet container or explicitly in your code.  You need to either have Spring instantiate it (by making it a `bean`, etc) or use `<context:spring-configured/>`.  I'm not sure if the latter will work if the servlet container instantiates the object as it will likely depend on the order in which things occur...

Comment: thanks for the comment. looking at the link reimeus has provided above http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19745187/spring-di-autowired-property-is-null-in-a-rest-service#19751981 , i think you may be right. i'm using both spring and jersey. i have used spring servlet in web.xml as suggested by mentioned solution, and i already had jersey-spring dependency exclusion correctly. but still getting null for autowire. will continue to play around this solution.

Answer (score 1):

Spring only know to autowire fields that have been marked as beans. From your code `CustomerDAO` is not a bean. For example to define it as a bean in the xml configuration file you need to add 
 `<bean id="customerDao" class="com.packagesNames.CustomerDaoImpl"/> in the xml file.` or to have the class annotated with `@Component` or to have it defined with `@Bean` in a `@Configuration` class.

Comment: thanks for comment. i didn't post CustomerDAOImpl code, but it does have @Component annotation. the problem is actually happening earlier, where CustomerBOImpl autowiring is failing at CustomerServiceImpl. (just updated main question with CustomerDAOImpl code) also i'm trying to avoid defining bean in xml if possible.

Answer (score 1):

Jersey 2 and Spring integration is now supported.

Jersey Docs: [Chapter 22. Spring DI](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/spring.html)

Blog: [Implementing Jersey 2 Spring Integration](http://practicingtechie.com/2014/02/08/implementing-jersey-2-spring-integration/)

Sample App: [Jersey's Hello World Spring WebApp](https://github.com/jersey/jersey/tree/2.5.1/examples/helloworld-spring-webapp)

However, as of this writing, Spring beans can't be injected directly into JAX-RS classes by using Spring XML configuration. Annotations (`@Autowired`, etc.) must be used.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. My injected bean in the resource class was always coming as `NULL`.

I spent 2 days trying to figure it out why I can't inject the Spring Bean into the JAX-RS resource class. Then I found the below in the [Jersey documentation](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/spring.html):

> "Limitations:
>
> Spring beans can't be injected directly into JAX-RS classes by using
>   Spring XML configuration"

Note: I was using Jersey 2 and Spring 3.x in my project.