# Spring autowire null value

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I have a problem with autowiring component with spring. Im trying inject bean (UserRepository) into java class Reader. When im using autowire annotation the object is allways null. I try add into spring-config.xml bean 'reader' whith property 'userRepository' but this not working too. What is missing?

spring-config.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

<context:component-scan base-package="reader" />
<context:annotation-config/>

<bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="org.sqlite.JDBC"/>
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:sqlite:C:/Users/Piotr/Downloads/projekt na projekt/IntelliDOM/IntelliDOM.sqlite"/>
    <property name="username" value=""/>
    <property name="password" value=""/>
</bean>

<bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
</bean>

<bean id="userRepository" class="repository.UserRepositoryHibernate">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory"/>
</bean>

</beans>
```

Reader.java:

```
@Service
@Path("/")
public class Reader {

@Autowired
private UserRepository userRepository;

@GET
@Path("/test")
public void test(){
    System.out.println("test");
    userRepository.findAll(); //this is allways null
}

@POST
@Path("/dom2")
public Response read(String nonParsedWords){
    Words parsedWords = WordParser.parseWords(nonParsedWords);

    for(String word : parsedWords.getWords()){
        System.out.println(word);
    }
    return Response.status(200).entity(nonParsedWords).build();
}

public void setUserRepository(UserRepository userRepository) {
    this.userRepository = userRepository;
}
}
```

Is there something wrong with context of application? Why this bean cant not be injected?
Spring version: 2.5.6

EDIT:
hibernate.cfg.xml:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
"-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD//EN"
"http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
  <session-factory>
  <property name="show_sql">true</property>
  <property name="format_sql">true</property>
  <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.SQLiteDialect</property>
  <property name="connection.driver_class">org.sqlite.JDBC</property>
  <property name="connection.url">jdbc:sqlite:IntelliDOM.sqlite</property>
  <property name="connection.username"></property>
  <property name="connection.password"></property>
  <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>

  <mapping class="entity.User"/>
  </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

Comment: Does UserRepositoryHibernate implements UserRepository?

Comment: `Reader` class is inside the `reader` package, right?

Comment: How are you initializing `Reader` class instances?

Comment: have you try `org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean` in class in `sessionFactory` ?, where have you defined hibernate dialect ?

Comment: @user3145373ツ I bet the injection process is fine and OP is initializing the bean manually: `new Reader();` or something similar.

Comment: @mserioli and cy3er - yes

Comment: @user3145373ツ - hibernate dialect is defined in hibernate.cfg.xml (<property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.SQLiteDialect</property>)

Comment: can you post that code ?

Comment: print `userRepository` check if it gives null or any other data print ?

Comment: @user3145373ツ - it prints "null"

Comment: means there is some configuration / xml problem.

Comment: This might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19745187/spring-di-autowired-property-is-null-in-a-rest-service