# Jersey Servlet not found after switching to Spring

Tags: java, spring, rest, servlets, jersey

I have a simple RESTful Java web service...

```
@Service
@Path("/getAccountBalance")
public class GetAccountBalanceService {

@Autowired
private ILicenseService licenseService;

@GET
@Path("/{param}")
public Response provideService(@PathParam("param") String licenseUUID) {

    License license = this.licenseService.getByUUID(licenseUUID);

    String output = "Balance on the account : " + license.getBalanceValue();

    return Response.status(200).entity(output).build();

}
```

At first I was getting an error where the bean licenseService was null even though I am autowiring it. So based on advice from another [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19745187/spring-di-autowired-property-is-null-in-a-rest-service#19751981) I swtiched to use the Spring servlet for jersey, thus in my web-xml I changed from com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer to...

```
    <servlet>
      <servlet-name>jersey-servlet</servlet-name>
      <servlet-class>
             com.sun.jersey.spi.spring.container.servlet.SpringServlet
      </servlet-class>
      <init-param>
         <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages</param-name>
         <param-value>com.freedomoss.crowdcontrol.api</param-value>
    </init-param>
      <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
```

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>jersey-serlvet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/service/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

But now when I start Tomcat I am getting the error..

```
  Dec 19, 2014 12:13:13 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig applicationWebConfig
 SEVERE: Parse error in application web.xml file at jndi:/localhost/mturk-web/WEB-INF/web.xml
 java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Servlet mapping specifies an unknown servlet name jersey-serlvet
```

Why is this happening? As you can see there is a servlet defined with that name in web-xml. If there was something wrong with loading that servlet why don't the logs tell that story?

Thanks.

Comment: Have you read the error and look at your `servlet-mapping`? Your servlet is named `jersey-servlet` NOT `jersey-servlet` the latter is what your `servlet-mapping` is pointing to.

Comment: I think @M.Deinum meant `serlvet` (but he's right). Voting to close as a typographical error

Comment: That what I meant indeed, damn you auto-correct :).

Comment: Thanks guys, that was indeed a type. Can't believe how I missed it (I started at that code for a while)